# can't install chatterbot module - 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, macos, chatterbot

I'm trying to install Chatterbot in my Mac with oficial guide: http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html

So, I'm getting an error when simply trying to see module version as the oficial guide shows.

```
➜  chatterbot git:(master) python --version
Python 2.7.10

➜  chatterbot git:(master) pip install chatterbot
Requirement already satisfied: chatterbot in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: python-twitter<4.0.0,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: chatterbot-corpus<1.0.0,>=0.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo<4.0.0,>=3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: jsondatabase<1.0.0,>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-twitter<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-twitter<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-twitter<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from nltk<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->chatterbot)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib->python-twitter<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->chatterbot)

➜  ~ python -m chatterbot --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatterbot/__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(chatterbot.__version__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

I've tried to install with pip and also with source.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a bug of `chatterbot`...

Comment: Wait... from which directory are you running that command? Given that python2 has implicit relative imports what's happening might be that you are inside the source tree, and the `import chatterbot` inside `__main__.py` leads to importing the module `chatterbot.chatterbot` instead of `chatterbot.__init__`

Answer (score 0):

I this will produce a version number

```
import chatterbot
chatterbot.__version__
```

The outcome something like this based installed chatterbot version

> '0.6.2'

Even after suggestion didn't worked, try to

> pip install chatterbot

If it is Linux flavor try to

> `sudo pip install chatterbot`